# ¿Cómo agregar una biblioteca estática al Makefile de Dev-C++?

Tags: c, windows, socket, dev-c++, makefile

Estoy tratando de implementar un protocolo que creé para sistemas Windows_NT usando la API win32 y para esto nececito hacer uso de la biblioteca `ws_32` que se encuentra en la ruta `C:\Program Files (x86)\Dev-Cpp\MinGW64\x86_64-w64-mingw64\lib32\libws_32.a` pero no sé cómo agregarla a las opciones del compilador, ya que, cada vez que edito el archivo *Makefile.win* y trato de compilar, el IDE sobreescribe el Makefile y compila desde ahí. ¿Alguién podría ayudarme a resolver este problema? Desde ya muchas gracias.

**P.D**: Uso el Entorno de Desarrollo Integrado Dev-C++ con MinWG64 en Windows 10.

Comment: visita aquí http://c.conclase.net/devcpp/?cap=libestatica Ahi se encuentra informacion acerca de las bibliotecas estaticas y sus aplicaciones con ejemplos suerte!!

Comment: Esto es más un comentario que una respuesta. Considera cambiarlo a la sección correspondiente o profundiza más en la respuesta.

Comment: Hola y ¡gracias por responder! Lamento haberte hecho perder el tiempo, pero ya resolví el problema. De igual forma, aceptaré la respuesta ya que resolví el problema con ese artículo. Saludos.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Ya resolví el "*problema*". Para modificar el archivo Makefile.win de cualquier proyecto en Dev-C++ hay que:

Compilar el proyecto mínimamente una vez (no importa el resultado que devuelva la compilación);

1. Ir a "**Opciones del proyecto**" (Atajo del teclado: Ctrl+H);
2. Seleccionar la pestaña "**Archivo MAKEFILE**";
3. Verificar la casilla "**Usar Makefile personalizado (no generar
   ninguno, usar éste)**";
4. Seleccionar el archivo Makefile.win anteriormene generado por
   Dev-C++; [image: Paso 4]
5. Editar el Makefile según queramos;

```
LIBS = -L"C:/Program Files/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/lib32" -L"C:/Program Files/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib32" -l"C:/Program Files/Dev-Cpp/MinGW64/x86_64-w64-mingw32/lib32/libws_32.a" -static-libgcc -m32
```

6. Volver a compilar (esta vez sí importa el resultado, ya que es la
   compilación "*real*") y...

¡Listo! nuestro proyecto quedó configurado para no sobrescribir el Makefile modificado.